# get html saved as string from db and use it as react html in react js

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to insert HTML as a string into the MongoDB and then get it in react app and put it in component as  html?
I've tested DomParser in js but It did not work.

Comment: What did not work, do you have an example of what you tried, where did you get stuck?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: Awesome))It's work

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property

```
const htmlString = `<h1>I'm a string with HTML!</h1>`;
const App = () => <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }} />;
```